# Vanity urls for assets in Angular 2

Tags: angularjs, angular

I have `tips.pdf` that I would like to live at `/tips`.

When a user manually types in `/tips` I want it to redirect to `/tips.pdf`, preferably in a new tab.

When I updated my routing module I get `Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'tips'`.

```
const ROUTES: Routes = [
  {
    path: '', redirectTo: '/home', pathMatch: 'full'
  },
  {
    path: 'home', component: HomeComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'fun', component: FunComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'tips', redirectTo: '../assets/pdfs/tips.pdf', pathMatch: 'full'
  }
]
```

Is this because I don't have a component? Obviously I don't want to create a component just for a stationary pdf in my asset folder.

Comment: I think that kind of redirect needs to be done by the server

Comment: I know how to do it on the server, but I was wondering if there's a way to accomplish it within Angular

Answer (score 0):

It's because you don't have any route maching '../assets/pdfs/tips.pdf'. The first redirection works because home is matching the second entry in `ROUTES`.

You don't need Angular to do that, you need to add the redirection in your server configuration.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think Angular can do that.

One thing you can try is create a dummy component that opens a url using `window.open`.

```
{
    path: 'tips', component: FilOpenerComponent 
}

export class FilOpenerComponent {
    constructor(private router: Router) {
       window.open("../assets/pdfs" + this.router.url + ".pdf");
    }
}
```

And you can further generalize this component using query params to know exactly where to look for the file.

Answer (score -1):

Either the current path or redirected path should have a component in Angular.
 so as mentioned in one of the answer the logic has to be added in component